# IO::Socket::IP  and Socket don't work on perl 5.8.8

Tags: perl, ipv6

I did a test with the code found on the IO::Socket::IP page:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::IP -register;

 my $sock = IO::Socket->new(
    Domain    => PF_INET6,
    LocalHost => "::1",
    Listen    => 1,
 ) or die "Cannot create socket - $@\n";

 print "Created a socket of type " . ref($sock) . "\n";
```

And the output I get on a perl 5.8.8 machine is:

`Cannot create socket - Address family for hostaname not supported`

While on a slackware machine with perl 5.12.3 it succeed.

So, it seems that upgrading Socket.pm to the latest version isn't enough to enable ipv6 support on perl 5.8.8.

Comment: `HTTP::AppServer` uses `HTTP::Server::Simple` that uses the core `Socket` module. So IPv6 will only work with versions of perl that have an IPv6 capable `Socket` module. Which version of `Socket` do you use?

Comment: Zagorax: Hacking this to get it to work is the wrong way to go about things and will likely leave you with a multitude of obscure bugs. Is there nothing at all you can do to get an upgrade to Perl v5.10?

Comment: @mugenkenichi, As I said, I installed the latest Socket module, it's version 2.002.

Comment: And does `Socket` work with IPv6 stand alone on your 5.8.8 machine?

Comment: @Borodin, Unfortunately not. I'm doing this work for the Genève CERN during the Google Summer of Code. Their virtual machine runs Scientific Linux 5, that is based on RHEL 5 (which has perl 5.8.8 installed). They have hundreds of virtual machines and it's unlikely they will upgrade perl core module on all of them... :(

Comment: @mugenkenichi, No, it doesn't. I did a test with IO::Socket::IP and I edited my question to consider the result. I need some more modules. Replacing `Socket.pm` wasn't enough.

Comment: Is this code run under "use strict"? I mean are you sure PF_INET6 is  defined? Try to use bare number constant (according to socket.h PF_INET6 == 10)

Comment: Yes, it does. I always add `use strict` and `use warnings` atop of my script.

Answer (score 0):

My best idea is to look at a list of module files your program has loaded (either explicitly or implcitly). This code should do the trick

```
use File::Spec;
print File::Spec->canonpath($_), "\n" for sort values %INC;
```

Look at each relevant file (obviously you can ignore things like `strict.pm`) to make sure the files you have updated are being used and to see if there is anything you have overlooked that could use an upgrade.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm leaving tomorrow, I'll try your solution when I'm back.

Answer (score 0):

As I already commented on the bug linked from your previous paste, `HTTP::Server::Simple` is simply not written for handling IPv6. It has lots of IPv4-specific code littered all over the place. You cannot enable this simply by installing some other module.

Once basic IPv6 support is working in `Socket`, independently of `HTTP::Server::Simple`, then you can go about fixing the code in `HTTP::Server::Simple` to support IPv6. To be clear here, this will involve editing `lib/HTTP/Server/Simple.pm` itself, and actually fixing the code. Remove the IPv4-specific parts and write some family-netural code instead; ideally using `IO::Socket::IP` itself rather than the raw `Socket`-using code it currently has. This will make it more standard and better supported in the future.

Again to summarise - the actual code needs rewriting here; no amount of mere module-installing will be sufficient.

Comment: Hi, I'm quite sure you're right as you're the developer of Socket.pm, but the last version of HTTP::Server::Simple perfectly handle ipv6 with perl 5.12.3, so why it should be impossible to manually upgrade some perl 5.8.8 modules to make it working?

Comment: Probably the right question is: my test with IO:Socket:IP shows that Socket.pm stand alone doesn't work with perl 5.8.8... how can I make it working?

Comment: Oh I see, I wasn't aware that a newer `HTTP::Server::Simple` could manage it. That's more interesting in that case.

Comment: LeoNerd, As I didn't find a solution yet, I changed the whole question to be more specific to the problem.